# Restore MarkLogic 10 Default Server & Database Configuration

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I tried moving **`default databases`** like **`Schemas`, `Security`, `Modules`** etc., to different directory location but suddenly the admin console access is revoked and now NO users are able to login.  Please help me as to how to restore default database to the default location and regain admin login access?

```
Error Log: **Warning: MarkLogic.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units**
Mounted forest abc locally on /a/b/abc read write (dm-2 xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
**Mounted forest Security locally on /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Security read write (dm-6 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered)**
```

Solution tried:

- Restart; but still, the login authentication is blocked

Comment: Did you try running "systemctl daemon-reload" as noted in the message? As a worst case, you can always stop ML, delete the ML data directory, which defaults to /var/opt/MarkLogic, and then start ML back up, at which point you'll need to go to host:8001 and setup the admin user again.

Comment: Yes, post restarting with the command "systemctl daemon-reload", the admin console is running but the console is not authenticating any user ids (I tried mine as admin id and one more developer user id)

Comment: How *exactly* did you do the move, step by step?  Was a copy or a move?  Did you use links/mounts to the new locations?  If you are entitled to Support, I would also recommend opening a ticket.

Comment: I have moved the forests thru XQuery: xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace ts="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tieredstorage" at "/MarkLogic/tieredstorage.xqy";

let $forest-ids := ("F1", "F2", "F3")
let $dbName := ("DB1")
let $dirName := "/dir/data"
return for $each in $forest-ids
return ts:forest-migrate(xdmp:forest($each), xdmp:host("newHostName"), $dirName, $dirName, $dirName, ("timeout=20"))

Comment: Both the data and security setup are restored and it solved the issue

Comment: Observation: While moving the "security" forest from one directory to another, the data of the forest replicated hence, the authentication failed.  Restoring the same from the backup helped solving the issue.